# Вывод ключа php

Tags: php, kohana

Привет всем.

Есть такая проблема, при инициализации конфига выдает ошибку.
т.е. вывод данных с 1, 1-1 по 1-4 работает.
А когда пытаюсь вывести с 2, 2-1 по 2-4 не работает.

Как можно разделить основные ключи 1 и 2.

```html
class Config extends Kohana_Model{
    
        function get($key){
    if($key == '1')
        return '1111111';

    if($key == '1-1'){
        return urlencode('2222222');
    }
    if($key == '1-2'){
        return urlencode('333333');
    }
    
    if($key == '1-3'){
        return urlencode('444444');
    }

    if($key == '1-4'){
        return urlencode('5555555');
    }



   
if($key == '2'){
        return '1111111111';
    }


if($key == '2-1'){
        return urlencode('1111111');
    }

if($key == '2-2'){
        return urlencode('2222222');
    }

if($key == '2-3'){
        return urlencode('3333333');
    }

if($key == '2-4'){
        return urlencode('44444444');
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: тут происходит что-то очень странное. не иначе чёрная магия

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5679f92443242a172943835cfc12cd273ed5efa9  ......ваш ужасно странный код работает

Comment: а через switch  не лучше сделать?

Comment: @tweeker а как это реализовать?

Comment: @ИльясБадыганов вот ссылка ( http://www.php.su/learnphp/cs/?sc ) Там прям показан пример с If и как его реализовать на SWITCH

Comment: @ИльясБадыганов вы бы лучше сказали что хотите сделать в целом... а то выглядит как один большой и ужасный костылииищще.. причем рабочий, но у вас типа что-то не работает... и вам предлагают поменять один костылииище на другой